# Chrome Extension Manifest V3 inject\execute local script

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to figure out how to add a script to a page via my simple chrome extension. Currently I have a script, mycoolscript.js which is a local file to my extension and I am using the following code (snippets including manifest) to add it to the current page.

I feel like I am close, the script tag is added to the head tag but when the onload fires I am seeing stating that coolObject is not defined. coolObject is returned from mycoolscript to the window. If I build a page manually or use tampermonkey this works perfectly. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong here?

manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["contentScript.css"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
        "resources": ["mycoolscript.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
    ]
```

contentScript.js

```
    function addMyCoolScript(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('mycoolscript.js');
        (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
        s.onload = function () {
            s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
            onScriptLoaded();
        };
    }
    
    function onScriptLoaded() {
        let apikey = "ABC123"
        let baseUrl = "example.com"
    
        coolObject.initialize(apikey, {
            baseUrl: baseUrl,
        });
        coolObject.runStartup();    
        coolObject.openSession();
    }
```

Comment: You probably don't need to create a script element at all because it runs in a different execution context so its functions/variables aren't directly accessible. If you want to use them in the content script then you should simply put its name in `js` field in manifest.json: `"js": ["mycoolscript.js", "contentScript.js"]`

Comment: OK I have done that but I am still getting a coolObject is not defined error when I load the page.

Comment: Scratch that!!! I started over and have it working as you suggested. Loading the script as part of the extension was the answer!